# Using Scope_identity with ExecuteNonScalar returns 1?

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to return the last inserted identity value through an asp.net application. I keep getting 1. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
    string ID="";
    const string statement = "INSERT INTO asp2(CustomerName,Email,CP,CPN) VALUES(@text1,@text2,@text3,@text4);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(statement))
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ST"].ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text1", TextBox1.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text2", TextBox4.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text3", TextBox2.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text4", TextBox3.Text);
            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            ID = command.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch{}
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns number of affected rows. You must use `ExecuteScalar` instead.

```
ID = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
```